# Unique items and inheretance

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, python-3.6

I was working on a problem with two parts:

1)  Create a class Foo() that creates unique instances based upon a single passed in value 'x'.  If multiple instances are attempted to be created with the same 'x' value, then only the first one should be kept.

Foo() works correctly.

2)  Create a class Bar() that inherits from Foo().  It should perform the same job as Foo() (unique items only) but allow for two variables, 'x' and 'y'.

Here's the odd part.  I got part 1 working.  I was working on part 2 when - Shazam! - part 2 appears to be working.  However, I have no idea why.  I did not think I had the 'y' checking part coded, but it looks like the whole thing is working.  Can somebody look at this and tell me why part 2 is working?

From objects f1 - f5, there are two unique items.

From objects f6 - f13, there are four unique items.

Grand total: 6 unique items, which is what I get when I run it.  But I have no idea how the uniqueness based upon the passed in 'y' parameter is being done.

My code:

```
seenx = {}
# seeny = {}


class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @classmethod
    def new(cls, x):
        if x not in seenx:
            seenx[x] = cls(x)
        return seenx[x]


f1 = Foo.new(10)
f2 = Foo.new(10)
f3 = Foo.new(20)
f4 = Foo.new(10)
f5 = Foo.new(20)

s = {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5}

for i in s:
    print(i)


class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x)
        self.y = y

    @classmethod
    def new2(cls, x, y):
        return super().new(x).new(y)


f6 = Bar.new2(10, 'abc')
f7 = Bar.new2(10, 'abc')
f8 = Bar.new2(20, 'xyz')
f9 = Bar.new2(10, 'abc')
f10 = Bar.new2(20, 'xyz')
f11 = Bar.new2(10, 'def')
f12 = Bar.new2(20, 'ghi')
f13 = Bar.new2(20, 'ghi')

s2 = {f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13}

for i in s2:
    print(i)
```

And the output:

```
<__main__.Foo object at 0x0D704F30>
<__main__.Foo object at 0x0D704EF0>
<__main__.Foo object at 0x0D722090>
<__main__.Foo object at 0x0D722030>
<__main__.Foo object at 0x0D722050>
<__main__.Foo object at 0x0D722070>
```

Comment: Your `Bar` approach actually doesn't work.  Try `Bar.new2(20, 'xyz')` and `Bar.new2(10, 'xyz')`.  These will both return the same object, which they should not.

Comment: You are correct.  Can you maybe point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a class that does this instance tracking using the [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) method.

```
class Foo:
    _instances = {}
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        if args not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[args] = super().__new__(cls)
        return cls._instances[args]
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class Bar(Foo):
    _instances = {}
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x)
        self.y = y
```

Comment: TypeError: super.__new__(Foo): Foo is not a subtype of super

Comment: @MarkS Just a typo, try the fixed version?